# Store certain values in JSON into parameters in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

brand new to Javascript.

I have figured out how to get data back from a Monday.com board, and it is returned as a JSON value like this:

```
{
"boards": [
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "column_values": [
                    {
                        "id": "location",
                        "title": "Location",
                        "type": "location",
                        "text": "Cape Town, South Africa"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "column_values": [
                    {
                        "id": "location",
                        "title": "Location",
                        "type": "location",
                        "text": "Paris, France"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "column_values": [
                    {
                        "id": "location",
                        "title": "Location",
                        "type": "location",
                        "text": "New York, NY, USA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

There are 3 items here, but this amount can be anything.

I need to get the location text (e.g. "Cape Town, South Africa") and then I need to use this later in an API call to get the weather of this location.

I finally managed to display in the console the location, like this:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.boardData.boards[0].items[0].column_values[0].text));
```

Obviously this then displays what I want, but only the value of the first item.

I need to do this dynamically to get all the locations, and I need to store this into variables, so that I can then make an API call to get the weather of each of the 3 (or more) locations.

I am totally lost and have been struggling for hours. Once I manage to do this, I still have no idea how I'll make the API call but one thing at a time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `text` with some amount of nested `.map`. Map boards => map items => map column_values. You will get an array of arrays of arrays. And then you can apply `.flat()` to unwrap them all. (`.flat(Infinity);` also can be used)

```js
const apiData={boards:[{items:[{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"Cape Town, South Africa"}]},{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"Paris, France"}]},{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"New York, NY, USA"}]}]}]};

const locations = apiData.boards
  .map((board) => board.items.map((i) => i.column_values.map((cv) => cv.text)))
  .flat(2);
console.log(locations);
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers work! not sure if I am allowed to ask a second question here or should log a new post. But I now have the locations object created, inside of my componentDidMount method. If I try and use it inside my render method to display on a web page, it says it is not defined. How do I use that value inside my render?

Comment: @user2725402 It will be better to create a new question honestly. But if you are creating `location` and setting it to the state with `setState` function (normal flow) - this update will be reflected only on next render, and on first render you will get an error about it is not defined. You should read about `conditional rendering` and use it here.

Comment: @user2725402 Additionaly, to not use the conditional rendering - you can initialize your `state` with `location: []`, empty array, and just update in in your `componentDidMount `. That way it will be defined on initial render

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```js
const rawData = {boards:[{items:[{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"Cape Town, South Africa"}]},{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"Paris, France"}]},{column_values:[{id:"location",title:"Location",type:"location",text:"New York, NY, USA"}]}]}]};

const locations = [];

for (const board of rawData.boards) {
  for (const item of board.items) {
    for (const value of item.column_values) {
      locations.push(value.text);
    }
  }
}

console.log(locations);
```

Answer (score 0):

So in javascript we have an array function [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), using which we can iterate over array that can be used here. It would look something like this:

```
let arr = boards[0].items.map(element => element.column_values[0].text)
```

and this arr will contain the list of all the city names, which you can further use to send the data to api.

(Edit: considering column_values to be array with one element only and items can have multiple elements)